# Input field suggessions are not showing properly on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using email input field, for forgot password password. But on Firefox it is not showing properly.

I am using below code

```
<div class="mainB">
<div class="centerBlock">
<form method="post">
    <div class="alignText">
       Enter Email Address:
        <input type="email" name="userEmail" required="required"
                pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,}@[a-zA-Z]{3,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" 
                maxlength="45" id="forgotPassTextField" />
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="alignCenter">
        <button class="btn  mt-15 btn-default  btn-custom" type="submit">
           Ok
        </button>
        <button class="btn  mt-15 btn-default  btn-custom" type="button"
                onclick="">
            Cancel
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The suggestions are showing at the bottom of the page and text field is at the top of page:

[image: 1]

MY CSS as follows:

```
.alignText {
    margin-left: 52px;
    text-align: left;
}
#forgotPassTextField {
    width: 252px;
}
#alignCenter {
    text-align: center;
}
.mainB {
    height: 585px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.centerBlock {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000000;
    height: 230px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: i think problem is because Firefox and chrome pick resolution differently can you share css also

Comment: @himanshu I have added my css, given only for textfield and button..

Comment: `<fmt:message ...>` isn’t HTML. If it is essential to the problem, describe how and tag the question accordingly. If not, remove it or replace it by suitable actual content and HTML code.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thats an jsp tag only for labeling, I have removed that now..can you please tell me why this happens only on firefox?

Comment: Looks like there is additional CSS that is the culprit (bootstrap?)

Comment: The code in the question does not produce the effect described in it.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela and steveax i have added complete css for this

Comment: I have just given a necessary code for this

Comment: The code now reproduces the issue in the sense that the “suggestion box” is displaced in Firefox (when you start typing something that begins the same way as some previous input in this form; note that the `pattern` attribute sets rather arbitrary-looking restrictions on the email address).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the “suggestions” box (the box that appears suggesting some previously entered value when you type something that matches the start of such a value) is that it is under the control of the browser. There is no specification on it and not much public documentation either.

In this case, that box is displayed because the `input` element is inside an element (the `div` with class `centerBlock`) on which a CSS transformation is applied, namely a simple translation in the *y* direction. It seems that Firefox gets confused and thinks that the `input` element is placed in a location where it would be without the transformation.

Thus, the fix is to remove `transform: translateY(-50%);`. For positioning the element, it is better to place it at the right place otherwise. In this case, it is relatively positioned, so you would just need to replace `top: 50%;` by `top: calc(50% - 115px);`. The value `115px` is 50% of the height of the `div` element.

The [`calc` construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) is not supported by IE 8 or earlier, but neither is [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).